# How to delete checked items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox

I want to have a `Button` that when clicked, removes all the checked items in the `ListView`. I already have all the xml items set up, I just don't know how to write the java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` displays data that comes from an `Adapter`. In order to remove items from the view the item needs to be removed from the `Adapter` and the view notified. In android the `Adapter` notifies the view by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

How to remove an item from the adapter depends on your particular adapter. The `SimpleCursorAdapter` gets its data from an underlying `Cursor`. To remove an item, the item should be removed from the underlying `Cursor`. For example using a `SQLiteCursor` a row in the database needs to be deleted.

If you use the `ArrayAdapter` just call `remove(T object)` on the adapter. It will automagically call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for you.

**update**:
I saw the code at git hub. Here are some pointers as how to get your app working as soon as possible.

Try refactoring your code in to smaller graspable parts. Start with [extracting some methods](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) to give parts of the large method understandable names.

The problem is that there might by hundreds of rows in the database and only enough views to fill the screen. Nowhere is it remebered what *rows* are checked, hence its not possible to remove them. You probably need to extend BaseAdapter or `SimpleCursorAdapter` to hold the state (checked or not) of the rows. Read up on the excellent android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

My point here is there is a distinction between the *view*, your `CheckBox`, and the *model* containing the data to display. So check out [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller). You can ignore the concept of controller for now.

Comment: What about a `SimpleCursorAdapter`? Same thing?

Comment: Updated the answer. For a `SimpleCursorAdapter` the hunts goes on - The underlying `Cursor` needs to be updated.

Comment: I understand where we're going, but I need to delete all my items with a checked `CheckBox`.

Comment: Alright, I see. So how do the view know whether to check or not check the checkbox? Obviously, this information is stored somewhere. Please edit the question so we can see how to iterate the information.

Comment: I don't know how to check to see if it is checked. I can try the `isChecked()` method.

Comment: `isChecked()` on your CheckBox instances will tell you if they are checked or not. The problem is Android will only create enough views (`CheckBox`es et al in this case) to fill the screen. Try adding enough items to scroll. Therefor the information whether a view *should* be checked or not needs to be stored elsewhere... Take a look at the documentation for ListView for starters.

Comment: I already have the Checkbox.isChecked set up as an if else statement, using the checkbox.setchecked method.

Comment: Can you please post relevant code. That is how the Adapter is set up, how the CheckBox is created, and so on.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a `CheckedTextView`, which combines both a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`. I already have a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, but I don't see a way to handle the checked state.